# Get data id modal bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I would like that when clicking the button it presents the data-id in the modal.

```
<button data-id="$id" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">OPEN</button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                           <?PHP echo $id; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                            </div>
```

I tried several tutorials and it did not work, will it be the jquery version?

How do I print the ID within the modal?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event on your button.

```
var myBtn = document.getElementByClassName("btn");

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
   var dataId = document.getElementByClassName("btn").dataset.id;
   console.log(">>>>dataId: ", dataId);

   document.getElementByClassName("modal-body").innerHTML = dataId;
});
```

Comment: I just added your code between <script> the modal opens but does not display the data-id

Comment: console `dataId`, make sure even listener is triggering and dataId exists. What is the console output now?

Comment: Where is this console.log generated?

Comment: Right click | inspect | console. See  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)

Comment: jQuery is not used in your code so, the error occurs. I have edited the answer to pure JavaScript. See if it works?